# How to access data in sheet in my Visual Studio Office Excel workbook?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2010

*I need to create a "Document level customization" with C# code (not and Excel Add-in!)*

I created a Visual Studio Office Excel 2010 Workbook project type. This creates a workbook with 3 sheets in my project. I added some "configuration" information to one of those sheets.

I need to access this **configuration** information programmatically (`Sheet1` contains a `button` - pressing on that button should

1. load **configuration** data
2. open a WinForm
3. present configuration data on that form,

but somehow I can't find how to do that...

If I try to initialize `Sheet1` class, compiler expects two parameters - `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Factory` and `IServiceProvider`, but I am calling this from a button that is placed on Sheet2 - so it's **after** Excel Workbook is already opened... shouldn't Sheet1 be initialized automatically?

So, how can I access `Sheet1` from my VSTO project's c# code?

### EDIT

[Please see project sample screencast here](http://screencast.com/t/l3tJgrFDkFkH)

I have a button on Sheet2, that should

1. load some data from Sheet1
2. initialize WinForm
3. add it as a DataSource for a ComboBox on that WinForm

I can not find a way how to read data from that Sheet1...

Comment: wow... I thought this must be something very basic... it must be not that easy, since there are no replies :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that there are not a lot developers (at least at stackoverflow) that work with Excel workbooks in Visual Studio / VSTO), but still this is is how I got this basic stuff working - in case if this is helpful to someone else

Since my code was in the Worksheet's *.cs file it turned out I can access project's xlsx file this way:

```
var excel = (Excel.Application)this.Application;
var xlbook = (Excel.Workbook)excel.ActiveWorkbook; 

var worksheets = xlbook.Worksheets;
var sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)worksheets["Sheet3"];
int row = 2;//1st row for column titles

while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[row, 2]).Value))
{
    var weight = ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[row, 3]).Value;
    row++;
}
```

Some additional things about processing data from Excel sheet in c# code, I found out (maybe that's helpful for someone):

1. the .NET type for Excel Cell is Excel.Range (at least I didn't
   find any other option)
2. when reading cell that is empty in Excel file, it's value on .NET side is null, not ""
3. values that seem to be strings on Excel side - can turn to be different types when loaded on c# side. I don't know if it's the best way, but I solved it like this:

var weight = (((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[row, 3]).Value);

```
if (weight is double)
{
    product.Weight = ((double)((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[row, 3]).Value).ToString();
}
else if (weight is string)
{
    product.Weight = ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[row, 3]).Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, how are you running this code? Do you have a ribbon and some control?

Comment: @FEST Hi, I have a button on Excel sheet (please see project sample in the question) and the code in sheet.cs file. I am creating a excel workbook project **not** an Excel add-on

Comment: @Prokuros hi, thx for the reply. Sory for being annoying but i couldn't understand how do you connect the button click event to code. I have an excel workbood project too. I have my code on ThisWorkbook.cs file. The only way i found to execute the code e to call my function on the ThisWorkbook_Startup. I would like to have the same behaviour as you. I even made a ribbon and a button inside but if i try to call the code i have to make a new instance of ThisWoorkbook and every interop object inside is null.

Comment: @FEST First - open excel sheet in your Excel workbook project, then add a control to your excel sheet and then through properties you can access it's events as for traditional winforms controls (or activate default event with double click on the control) Here is a small video showing this in action, I hope this helps: http://screencast.com/t/dzExmvCM

Comment: Thank you :) I don't remember if i tried such thing or not although what I want is a bit different that will help me get going :)

Comment: yes.. I am trying to figure out VSTO for excel and except for 2 or 3 articles to get started it is VERY lonely :(